# XCode 4.4 Auto @Synthesize failing on an XCode 4.3 Project

Tags: xcode, synthesize

It's as simple as that.

Running Lion.

1. I just upgraded to XCode 4.4
2. loaded my most recent XCode 4.3 project file
3. commented out one @synthesize line of code
4. and errors abound.  :(

Verified compiler is set to 'LLVM 4.0'.

Then I did the same test but created a new project within XCode 4.4, and voila!  Auto @synthesize works within a 4.4 project.

Auto @synthesize *also* seems to work on *new* properties added to the code.  But existing old one generate an error.

Anyone else experience this?
Any other things I should check for?

I really want the auto generation features to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Might sound stupid, and maybe you've already done this - but have you tried clean building the project?

Comment: Cleaned and even deleted all Derived Data.  I don't know what else XCode 4.4 is hanging on to with that 4.3 project.  <weird>

Comment: Okay - maybe try the option to convert to Modern Objective-C (it's under the Edit | Refactor menu

Comment: What kind of property are you trying to auto-synthesize, by the way. Because you can't auto-synth readonly properties. Just a thought.

Comment: 'convert to Modern Objective-C' did nothing and simply outputs "No source changes necessary".  So it doesn't even remove the synthesize statements, nor does it solve my issue.  The property I'm dealing with is a simple 'int'.  No big deal.  It should "just work".  If I create a second 'property in X', without a synthesize, the compiler works.  But on existing properties, when I remove the synthesize, the compiler complains with errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Error isn't the way you declare the property but in the way that you use it.

Auto-synthesized properties create a backing store with **a leading underscore by default**.

So in your code when you have a property declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *sectorLabel;
```

and you auto-sythesize - something like this is being auto-generated for you by the compiler:

```
@synthesize sectorLabel = _sectorLabel;
```

Now you can access it through the the property:

```
self.sectorLabel;
```

Or, you can access the backing store directly with:

```
_sectorLabel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

So this is what I did.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
// Public:

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *sectorLabel;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

//@synthesize sectorLabel;
```

And then this error popped up.

> ViewController.m:48:2: Use of undeclared identifier 'sectorLabel'; did
>   you mean '_sectorLabel'?

It resolved the moment I changed the code to:

```
self.sectorLabel
```

XCode 4.3 compiled and worked fine without the need for having the 'self.' keyword.  But XCode 4.4 seems to have gotten more strict about it.

Comment: I like the new strictness of Xcode. The updated compiler is more strict everywhere and does a great job.

Comment: no, this doesn't solve the problem. You should be able to omit @synthesize and still use _sectorLabel if it is done correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the answer accepted is that you just changed the behavior of your code by adding the self.property.

Accessing the ivar versus the property are two different things.  The correct answer would be to change the code to use the ivar correctly by adding the underscore.

This is not about strictness its about a change to the default property synthesization for xcode.  Also, in most style guides you will read that Apple discourages _ivar names so I guess thats out the window.

In my code I only use self. when I INTEND to access through the property getter and setter.  Not changing my existing code for this behavior its a waste of time.

Comment: The current recommendation is to prefer the use of properties over direct access.

Comment: Thats ok for code consistency, however, I am not willing to invoke an objc_invoke call for simple property accesses which happen alot in any app.  I only use property access internally in an implementation to set a value for its retention or for the dealloc method.  Otherwise its just a performance hit.  Also, since the accessors and mutators are autogenerated, there is no reason to use them internally since there is no internal behavior besides simple access of the value.  Just my opinion.  I also wish they hadnt defaulted to _ prefixes.

Comment: @stackmonster there is no reason for you to care about that "performance" hit unless your profiling indicates that it is causing a bottleneck in your app.  Premature optimization causes far more problems than it solves, and the overhead in this case is miniscule.

Comment: Its not premature optimization - calling a dynamic dispatch to access a simple value is ridiculous.  Properties exist for the consumer of the object not for the internal instance.

Comment: There are many applications where it would be foolish to consider use of objc_msgSend() for every ivar access in the initial implementation.  The meme against "premature optimization" has obvious pitfalls when applied to every programming task uncritically.