# reload Tableview over a Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to Reload my TableView with a Button Click,
I read a lot of stuff, but I found just 
that I have to 
write`[tableView reloadData]` the Problem is, in my own Function i dont have tableView I linked my 
`ÌBoutlet UITableView *myTable`with the table and write the functions `[myTable reloadData]`
but nothing happen.

in a section View i can add and delete items.
If i change to the view with the table, they are not updated (maybe a polling updater would be better, but its the same)
now i want to refresh my tableview to show the new cells

Do you have a good idea for me?
Thanks

EDIT:

I wrote down
in .h

`IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;`

`@property UITableView *myTable;`

in .m

`@synthesize myTable`

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender
 {
   [self.myTableView reloadData];
 }
```

but nothing happen if i press the Button.
I set a `NSLog`, to check the functionality in the function

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: did you change something in the table for something to happen?

Comment: Did you add "@synthesize myTable" too?

Comment: Yes I delete or add im my array, no i didn't @synthesize

Comment: Enable breakpoints and then check out if tableview's `numberOfRowsInSection` method gets called or not. You could also check out whether number of rows are different then existing or not. Could you explain the way you are adding/deleting your objects?

Comment: You didn't use @synthesize so it's [self.myTable reloadData]; in new Xcode.

Comment: I think you will gain little from the answer of this question as you are failing to grasp a fundamental object-oriented concept; that of instance variables and their scope.  You need to do more research/study before worrying about reloading table views.

Comment: I didnt get a connection between myTable and the table in nib..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using new version of Xcode that you don't need to @synthesize in your .m file when you linked your tableView to your .h file like you did in terms of @property.

Here is what's happening when you define a @property in you .h file:

1. you use synthesize like this:

   @synthesize myTable;

so use reloadData like this:

```
[myTable reloadData];
```

2. you use synthesize like this:

   @synthesize myTable=_myTable;

so use reloadData like one of these:

```
either [_myTable reloadData]; or [self.myTable reloadData];
```

3. Or you didn't use any @synthesize:

And in your case (new version of Xcode without any @synthesize) you just need to write one of these if you didn't use @synthesize

> [_myTable reloadData];

or

```
[self.myTable reloadData];
```

Hope it's helpful. I don't explain how to create IBAction or use delegate because I saw you are doing it right.

Good luck

Update1: some resources for Auto @synthesize feature in Xcode 4.4 and later:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html

[XCode 4.4 Auto @Synthesize failing on an XCode 4.3 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709210/xcode-4-4-auto-synthesize-failing-on-an-xcode-4-3-project)

Update2: I just saw you said it would be better to do this by pull to refresh system. It would be better to give some detail about the app you are building like the iOS version. If it's 6.0 or later you can use the native pull to refresh method like this:

http://www.lextech.com/2012/10/ios-6-pull-to-refresh-tutorial/

Or if it is not iOS 6.0 you can always use EGOTableViewPullRefresh I've used it and it works great even with iOS 6.0 and later.

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Comment: That's alright it happens. There is some useful information about pull to refresh if you like cause the button may not be the best approach since almost every apps use pull to refresh method. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

First put `UITableView` to `xib` and properly connect to outlet and create `@property` in .h file  and `@synthesize` to .m file
then use following code (`self.tableView`).

```
-(IBAction)btnPressed:(UIButton *) Sender
{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

may be helpful for you :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First you check that the link to that variable is still persisted. If link is OK then just call

```
[self.tableview reladData];
```

If the link is broken, then first link the variable to the `UITableView` from the xib then try to call the same as above.

Hope this will help you.